# Double while loops not responding

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, while-loop, pygame

Right now, I am working on a small RPG with 3 classes and the ability to have your own username. I have a problem with my main script. The problem is, the bolded `if` statement needs to be a while loop in order to add my next piece, the main menu. However when I try to use the while keyword it causes the game to stop responding. 
Thanks in advance to anyone who helps in any way.

Here is my code:

```
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()

    gameDisplay.fill(green)

    while User_name == None:
        User_name = Username.ask(gameDisplay,"username")
        print User_name + "'s run/dio"

    if Class_Choice == None:
        Choice_wall().paint(gameDisplay)
        Class_Choice = Choice_wall().Choice(pygame.mouse.get_pos(
            [0],0,pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0],0,0)


    pygame.display.update()
clock.tick(30)
```

Here are the functions:

```
 def Choice(self, c1,c2 , p1,p2,p3):
        while p1 == 0:
            if 0 <= c1 <= 319 and p1 == 1 :
                return "warrior"
            elif 320 <= c1 <= 639 and p1 == 1:
                return "archer"
            elif 640 <= c1 <= 960 and p1 == 1:
                return "mage"

def get_key():
  while 1:
    event = pygame.event.poll()
    if event.type == KEYDOWN:
      return event.key
    else:
      pass

def display_box(screen, message):
  "Print a message in a box in the middle of the screen"
  fontobject = pygame.font.Font(None,18)
  pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,0,0),
                   ((screen.get_width() / 2) - 100,
                    (screen.get_height() / 2) - 10,
                    200,20), 0)
  pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,255,255),
                   ((screen.get_width() / 2) - 102,
                    (screen.get_height() / 2) - 12,
                    204,24), 1)
  if len(message) != 0:
    screen.blit(fontobject.render(message, 1, (255,255,255)),
                ((screen.get_width() / 2) - 100, (screen.get_height() / 2) -     10))
  pygame.display.flip()

def ask(screen, question):
  "ask(screen, question) -> answer"
   pygame.font.init()
  current_string = []
  display_box(screen, question + ": " + string.join(current_string,""))
  while 1:
    inkey = get_key()
    if inkey == K_BACKSPACE:
      current_string = current_string[0:-1]
    elif inkey == K_RETURN:
      break
    elif inkey == K_MINUS:
      current_string.append("_")
    elif inkey <= 127:
      current_string.append(chr(inkey))
    display_box(screen, question + ": " + string.join(current_string,""))
  return string.join(current_string,"")
```

Comment: What bolded "if"? The last part of your code isn't properley in code format and indentation looks like it's messed up.

Comment: Could you be more specific with what happens? Does it freeze before or after you input your username?

Comment: You already have a game loop, you don't have another one inside of it.

Comment: Sorry I meant to bold the second if

Comment: It freezes after I input the username

Comment: thanks again to anyone who can help, also if need be I can give you the entire script

Comment: use `print()` to see what values you have in variables (ie. `print(Class_Choice)`) and which part of code is executed (ie. `print("i'm in: if")` - it helps to find problem.

Comment: BTW: use `lower_case` names for variables, functions/methods and instances to make code more readable - ie. `user_name`. We use `CamelCase` only for classes. Now I don't know if `Choice_wall()` is function or some class.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is almost certainly the loop in your `Choice_Wall.Choice` method:

```
while p1 == 0:
```

Since `p1` never changes in the loop (and it will never return if the loop condition was met), you're always going to loop forever if that condition is `True` the first time the method is called. You probably need to move the calls to `pygame.mouse.get_pos` and `pygame.mouse.get_pressed` inside the loop for there to be any chance of it working the way you intend.

An alternative might be to remove the inner loop entirely, since the `if Class_Choice == None` line in calling code will cause it to keep calling `Choice` on each iteration of the main loop until a choice is made.

Some further notes unrelated to the infinite loop issue: It would also be a lot more natural to create a `Class_Wall` instance just once, rather than twice on each frame it is needed. Of course, you might not even need a class at all if it doesn't contain any state (just one or more functions, like you're using for the username above). And as another user commented, it can be very helpful for other people's understanding if you follow a more typical naming convention in your code, such as `lowercase_with_underscores` for your function, method and module names (reserving `CapitalizedNames` for classes).

Comment: Thank you for the tips I will do my best to follow them in the future. However, I need some way for the game to wait until the if statement is false before moving past it.any tips

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out Thanks for the tips I will try harder to format it correctly in the futre